# Swift, using UISwipeGestureRecongizer

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, uigesturerecognizer, uiswipegesturerecognizer

i'm currently working on my first app using Swift 1.2 and Xcode 6.3, and have run into a wall.

So far I two sprites spawning above the view and dropping below the view

```
func spawnSquare() {
    let square = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Square")
    square.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: square.size)
    square.physicsBody?.dynamic = true

    let positionStart = CGPointMake(size.width * 0.5, size.width * 2.0)
    let positionEnd = CGPointMake(size.width * 0.5, size.height * -2.0)

     square.position = positionStart
            addChild(square)


    let shapesMovment = SKAction.moveTo(positionEnd, duration: shapeSpeed)
        square.runAction(shapesMovment)
}

func spawnCircle() {

    let circle = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Circle")
    circle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody (circleOfRadius:    
    circle.size.width/2 )
    circle.physicsBody?.dynamic = true

    let positionStart = CGPointMake(size.width * 0.5, size.width * 2.0)
    let positionEnd = CGPointMake(size.width * 0.5, size.height * -2.0)

    circle.position = positionStart
            addChild(circle)


    let shapesMovment = SKAction.moveTo(positionEnd, duration: shapeSpeed)
        circle.runAction(shapesMovment)
        }
```

Now I want to be able to swipe one of the sprites to the left or right, but i can't figure out how 
to implement a movement action with the UISwipeGestureRecogniser.

I've added two GestureRecongizers to didMoveToView

```
  let swipeLeft: UISwipeGestureRecognizer  = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("swipedLeft:"))
    swipeLeft.direction = .Left
    view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)

    let swipeRight: UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("swipedRight:"))
    swipeRight.direction = .Right
    view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)
```

And I added two functions at the bottom of GameScene so a println will state that i swiped

```
func swipedRight(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection) {
    println("Swiped Right")

   }
   func swipedLeft(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection) {
        println("Swiped Left")
    }
```

Now i'm asuming that i can just wright a code in one of the swiped functions to tell the SwipeGesture that i want to move a sprite,
but i have no idea where the begin and i haven't had much luck looking around the net for an answer so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you want to be able to drag the nodes around and throw them. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28259980/2158465

Answer (score 1):

Swipe gesture recognizers are "one-shot" deals. You get told "The user swiped!" and that's it. You can't have the user drag your sprite based on a swipe gesture.

If you want a fixed action on a swipe (like animating the sprite off the side) then a swipe will work fine.

Your swipedRight and swipedLeft functions are wrong. The target method for gesture recognizers always passes one and only one parameter: The gesture recognizer.

A gesture recognizer has a parameter for the view it's attached to.

You need to rewrite swipedRight and swipedLeft functions with a swipe gesture recognizer as the only parameter.

Then in the body of the function you need to fetch the view property from the gesture recognizer (your sprite). You can then do whatever animation you want on that view. (