# How to flick a SKSpriteNode like a soccer ball

Tags: ios, objective-c, skspritenode, skphysicsbody, skphysicsworld

If I had a SKSpriteNode on the screen, how would I be able to flick it so that it would simulate the physics of a soccer ball being kicked. [how to throw SKSpriteNode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28245653/how-to-throw-skspritenode) I am guessing that it would be sort of like this question, but instead of the node following your finger first before it is flicked shouldn't happen. It should look like when you flick you are swiping towards the node and then once your finger hits the node it moves it like the physics of a soccer ball. Can anyone give me a place to start in order to achieve this??

Comment: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_7_Sprite_Kit_Collision_Handling_Tutorial

Comment: @AdrianB does this show how to flick an SKSpriteNode?? I don't see it...

Comment: My apologies. It sounded like you were starting off at ground zero and were looking for a place to start. I've found techtopia tutorials very helpful. Gesture recognizers as they relate to SKSpriteNodes are discussed here. http://www.raywenderlich.com/44270/sprite-kit-tutorial-how-to-drag-and-drop-sprites

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the `touchesBegan` method and `touchesMoved` method.  Basically, keep track of the last position of the touch, along with the timestamp (using `NSTimeInterval`), and on each `touchesMoved` check if the soccer ball has the touch location inside it (using `[soccerBall containsPoint:location]`.  Then, calculate the force that you should impart on the ball (compare timestamps, and compare positions), and then run:

```
[soccerBall.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(dx, dy)];
```

Replace `dx` and `dy` with the results of your calculations.  You may wish to add a scale value to make sure that you get the results you are looking for.