# Dragging an SKSpriteNode only when touched

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift2, skspritenode

I have an `SKSpriteNode` that I want to drag around the screen via `touchesMoved`. However, I do not want the sprite to move if the touch didn't originate on the location of the sprite in the first place (no skipping around the scene).

I have a intermittent solution but believe something is both more elegant and more functional as this solution doesn't work correctly - it appears as if the sprite location doesn't keep up with the touch location if the user drags the sprite very fast.

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        var touchPoint : CGPoint = location
        var muncherRect = muncherMan.frame
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(muncherRect, touchPoint)) {
            muncherMan.position = location
        } else {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28245653

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement these three methods to achieve what you want: `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved` and `touchesEnded`. When you touched `muncherMan`, set `muncherManTouched` true which indicated `muncherMan` would probably be moved in the next frame. When finishing the move or touch, set `muncherManTouched` false and wait for the next touch.

Here's the example code. I add a name for `muncherMan` so we can determine which node is being touched in `touchesBegan`.

```
var muncherManTouched = false
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */
    ...
    muncherMan.name = "muncherMan"
    self.addChild(muncherMan)
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */ 
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let nodeTouched = self.nodeAtPoint(location)
        if (nodeTouched.name == "muncherMan") {
            muncherManTouched = true
        }
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        if (muncherManTouched == true) {
            muncherMan.position = location
        }
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    muncherManTouched = false
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked perfectly. Are you able to point me in the direction to know why mine was intermittently working?